# Why app will not create icon if add "<data android:scheme="file"/>" in AndroidManifest.xml?

Tags: android, xml

I add `<data android:scheme="file"/>` to `AndroidMainfest.xml`, then my app doesn't create icon in desktop after install. Why?

Here is the AndroidMainfest.xml:

```
<application android:name="FileManagerApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
             android:label="@string/app_name"
             android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
             android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
            android:name=".tvfileexplorer.folders.FolderActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTranslucentTheme"
            android:label="@string/app_name">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <data android:scheme="file"/>
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

</application>
```

Comment: Any reason for adding that line?

Comment: @degrigorash May be I make you Misunderstand, after app install, app will show a icon in android, I am not saying `INSTALL_SHORTCUT`.

Comment: @MehulJoisar at the beginning, it is just someone refer that if you want to filter broadcast from sdcard, I will need this.